# Prove by contradiction that any sequence of five distinct integers must contain a 3-chain.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Define a $3$-chain to be a (not necessarily contiguous) subsequence
of three integers, which is either monotonically increasing or monotonically decreasing. We
will show here that any sequence of five distinct integers will contain a $3$-chain. Write
the sequence as ${a}_{1},{a}_{2},{a}_{3},{a}_{4},{a}_{5}$. Note that a monotonically increasing sequences is one in which each term is greater than or equal to the previous term. Similarly, a monotonically
decreasing sequence is one in which each term is less than or equal to the previous term.
Lastly, a subsequence is a sequence derived from the original sequence by deleting some
elements without changing the location of the remaining elements. [Source](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/assignments/MIT6_042JF10_assn02.pdf)

(a) Assume that ${ a }_{ 1 }<{ a }_{ 2 }$. Show that if there is no $3$-chain in our sequence, then ${a}_{3}$` must be less than ${a}_{1}$. (Hint: consider ${a}_{4}$!)

(b) Using the previous part, show that if ${ a }_{ 1 }<{ a }_{ 2 }$ and there is no $3$-chain in our
sequence, then ${ a }_{ 3 }<{ a }_{ 4 }<{ a }_{ 2 }$.

(c) Assuming that ${ a }_{ 1 }<{ a }_{ 2 }$ and ${ a }_{ 3 }<{ a }_{ 4 }<{ a }_{ 2 }$, show that any value of ${ a }_{ 5 }$ must result in a $3$-chain.

(d) Using the previous parts, prove by contradiction that any sequence of five distinct integers must contain a $3$-chain.

So, I completed parts (a), (b), and (c). I am stuck on part (d).

What I understand thus far:

When we assumed "there is no $3$ chain in our sequence" in part (a), that's the proof by contradiction part. The only caveat is that we are assuming ${a}_{1} < {a}_{2}$.
So, by analyzing parts (a), (b), and (c), where all of them are contingent on ${ a }_{ 1 }<{ a }_{ 2 }$, we can see that:

(a) says that ${ a }_{ 1 }<{ a }_{ 2 }$ AND no $3$-chain implies that ${ a }_{ 3 }<{ a }_{ 1 }$

(b) says that ${ a }_{ 1 }<{ a }_{ 2 }$ AND no $3$-chain implies that ${ a }_{ 3 }<{ a }_{ 4 }<{ a }_{ 2 }$

(c) says that ${ a }_{ 1 }<{ a }_{ 2 }$ AND ${ a }_{ 3 }<{ a }_{ 4 }<{a}_{2}$
 implies that there is a $3$ chain.

So, by putting (b) and (c) together we get:

no $3$-chain implies ${ a }_{ 3 }<{ a }_{ 4 }<{ a }_{ 2 }$ which implies a $3$-chain. This is a contradiction. Thus, there must be a $3$-chain. (Given that ${a}_{1} < {a}_{2}$).

So, I have have utilized parts (a), (b), and (c), but I was assuming that ${a}_{1} < {a}_{2}$. What can I do to complete my proof? Am I even heading in the right direction?

I am also somewhat new to proof writing. I am doing this course through MIT OCW to get a leg up on the Discrete Math class I will have to take in the future. I would like help with constructing an elegant proof for this. I do not know how to take all of these ideas and organize them all, logically, in order to turn it into a complete and elegant proof.

Please note that a direct answer will not help me. I would like a hint and possibly even follow-on guidance in order to complete this.

Comment: You are headed in the right direction.  This is a proof by contradiction.  The proof starts off by assuming the statement you're trying to prove is false.  In your case once you do that you are considering each of the different cases of this problem.  You have shown that under one additional constraint that there must be a 3-chain.  now you have to pick one or more constraints and show that under each of those constraints there must be a 3-chain.  Basically what you are doing is breaking the problem down into a bunch of smaller problems.

Comment: Did you get there in the end? I'm just on the same exercise and it's a head scratcher for me...